# How to query with typeorm on postgres?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, syntax-error, typeorm

I  was looking all over the place for a source on TypeORM but I couldn't find any that has a good description on example. Below is my code. It tells me that there is a syntactical error somewhere near the "."

I have 3 tables. I join all 3 together and select the one within the past 3 days that has a subscription Id.

```
  async getRegisteredButNotpaidUser(): Promise<OrganizationUser[]> {
    const now = new Date()
    const remind_date = new Date()
    remind_date.setDate(now.getDate() - 3)
    return this.createQueryBuilder('organizationUser')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('organizationUser.organization', 'organization')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('organizationUser.user', 'user')
      .where('NOT organization."subscription" IS NULL')
      .andWhere('user."createdAt" < :remind_date', { remind_date })
      .select(['user."email"', 'user."name"', 'user."surname"', 'public.organization_user."createdAt"'])
      .getMany()
  }
```

Error message

```
[Nest] 21337   - 03/30/2021, 6:39:41 AM   [ExceptionsHandler] syntax error at or near "." +43804ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "."
    at new QueryFailedError (/home/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (/home/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (/home/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:146:19)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (/home/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:233:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /home/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:10
    at Parser.parse (/home/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:126:14)
[3/30/2021, 6:39:41 AM] info: ::1 - - [30/Mar/2021:06:39:41 +0000] "GET /someapi HTTP/1.1" 500 52 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8"
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "organization_user" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "roles" text NOT NULL DEFAULT 'basic', "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "valid" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true, "userId" uuid, "organizationId" uuid, CONSTRAINT "UQ_9625fda29f4e555434bd4cc33ed" UNIQUE ("userId", "organizationId"), CONSTRAINT "PK_b93262ca4d9016837d22ab6e1e0" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))

CREATE TABLE "organization" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "name" character varying NOT NULL, "organizationId" character varying NOT NULL, "country" character varying NOT NULL, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), CONSTRAINT "UQ_7867970623575b3f2561516414d" UNIQUE ("organizationId"), CONSTRAINT "PK_472c1f95a34def4b3abb129cd67" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))

CREATE TABLE "user" ("id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), "name" character varying, "surname" character varying, "email" character varying NOT NULL, "phone" character varying, "password" character varying, "lang" character varying, "department" character varying, "title" character varying, "location" character varying, "img" character varying, "thumbnail" character varying, "status" text NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending', "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "lastActivity" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), CONSTRAINT "UQ_e12875dfb2b1d42d6d6c5377e22" UNIQUE ("email"), CONSTRAINT "PK_cace3a129ff2f2522dd42473760" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

[image: Schema]

This is the query I was trying to convert to typeorm:

```
select public."user".email, public.organization_user."createdAt", public."user"."name" , public."user".surname, public.organization."subscriptionId" 
from public.user
join public.organization_user on public.organization_user."userId" = public.user.id  
join public.organization on public.organization_user."organizationId" = public.organization.id 
where public.organization."subscriptionId" is null
```

Comment: Hi! We need a bit more detail to be able to help you here. Please click [edit] under the question and add the schema of the tables in your database (the "create table" statements are a good way of sharing this), and the exact error message you received from that code.

Comment: Incidentally, the product is called "PostgreSQL" or "Postgres", never "Postgre".

Comment: @IMSoP I've included a schema underneath, thank you.

Comment: I should have mentioned, all details as text please. Images are no use to somebody trying to replicate the problem, and problematic for anyone with visual impairments or just reading on a small screen. That's why I suggested Create Table statements. We also need the exact error message you got - it may mean more to someone else than it does to you.

Comment: @PhanNguyen can you share the generated query? Use `getSql()` or `printSql()`.

Comment: @EmptyBrain SELECT user."email", user."name", user."surname", public.organization_user."createdAt" FROM "organization_user" "organizationUser" LEFT JOIN "organization" "organization" ON "organization"."id"="organizationUser"."organizationId"  LEFT JOIN "user" "user" ON "user"."id"="organizationUser"."userId" WHERE NOT organization."subscription" IS NULL AND user."createdAt" < $1

Answer (score 0):

I just removed select from the query and it works. It returns all columns.

One problem I have with this approach is that it doesn't allow me to remove the unused columns from joining the tables.

```
  async getRegisteredButNotpaidUser(): Promise<OrganizationUser[]> {
    const now = new Date()
    const remind_date = new Date()
    remind_date.setDate(now.getDate() - 7)
    return this.createQueryBuilder('organizationUser')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('organizationUser.organization', 'organization')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('organizationUser.user', 'user')
      .where('organization."subscriptionId" IS NULL')
      .andWhere('organization."createdAt" <= :remind_date', { remind_date })
      .getMany()
  }
```